# Is this a good approach for using MVC for multiple views?

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I'm using MVC to organise an Maths Game application that has multiple classes that are the following:

- `MathsGame.java`: Main class. Currently holds CardLayout which screen classes are contained in and runs the application along with other controller-like actions.
- `DiffScreen.java`: Implements components and contains methods for use on the difficulty selection screen. Is extended from `MigJPanel` and is essentially a mix of a Model/View.
- `GameScreen.java`: Implements components and contains methods for use on the game screen. Is extended from `MigJPanel` and is essentially a mix of a Model/View.
- `EndGameScreen.java`: Implements components and contains methods for use on the end game screen. Is extended from `MigJPanel` and is essentially a mix of a Model/View.
- `MigJPanel.java`: Extends `JPanel` and sets layout to `MigLayout` and adds a matte border.
- `ScreenInterface.java`: Is implemented by `DiffScreen`, `GameScreen`, and `EndGameScreen` and contains `final` variables and an `enum`.

I've watched some tutorials and read up on MVC, but a lot of the resources I've found on it deal with very basic programs; having one model, one view, one controller, and a main class.

I have an idea of how I must go about refactoring my program to work with MVC, but I'm unsure about a couple of things.

1. Am I right in saying that from what classes I have above, I should split `DiffScreen`, `GameScreen`, and `EndGameScreen` into Model and View classes for each? Additionally, would it be better to create one Controller class or—as I've seen suggested—not bother and instead combine it with my Main `MathsGame` class? An approach I was suggested to use in a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27557326/2637416) whereby I could implement a Controller interface seems useful too, but I'm not exactly sure if/how that would work with my new code.
2. Would it be helpful/needed for a project this small to split the Model, View, and Controller classes into their own sub-packages and keep `MathsGame` in the main package?

**Further Clarification:**

I'm essentially wondering if having these classes would be a good implementation of MVC:

- `MathsGame.java`: As a main class, or possibly being my controller. Could also possibly implement a controller interface as suggested in the linked answer above.
- *These 3 possibly being inside their own sub-packages, let's say `GamePackage.Views`*

  - `DiffView.java`
  - `GameView.java`
  - `EndGameView.java`
- *These 3 possibly being inside their own sub-packages, let's say `GamePackage.Model`*

  - `DiffModel.java`
  - `GameModel.java`
  - `EndGameModel.java`
- `Controller.java`: Won't be needed if MathsGame is both my main class and controller class. Could be in its own sub-package `GamePackage.Controller` if needed.
- `MigJPanel.java`
- `ScreenInterface.java`

**Additional:**

- I've looked up on Model-View-Presenter. It looks to be similar and better suited to whole applications. It seems these questions are valid for that too. If this would be more fitted to what I want to do, I would be okay with that too.

I'm hope I've explained myself well enough. It is for a college project but I missed a lot last year due to illness so I'm a bit confused on these aspects. If I can clarify any part better, please leave a comment. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: It's hard to answer from your question. In general, MVC is a means to separate your data (model), presentation (view), and logic (controller). For a game with overlapping and transitioning states, it a little more complicated. But the general idea holds. Your controller gets a model and then the controller renders the view using that model.

Comment: @Alex I'll add further clarification.

Comment: In your example, the `MathsGame` class should be the controller, and the visible UI classes like `GameScreen` are views. It seems like you are maybe missing model classes. Usually these would include some data classes and maybe persistence classes (e.g., DAO).

Comment: @Alex Okay. Should I forego having a separate controller and main class as [this](http://www.newthinktank.com/2013/02/mvc-java-tutorial/) example has? My naming of UI classes is misleading as they were made before I began using MVC. At the moment, they contain the views and model behaviour for each screen, such as classes related to that screen. So it's not really MVC and needs to be changed.

Comment: @Alex I've added further clarification if that helps understand my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering based on the assumption that your user interfaces(`GameView`, `EndGameView`) contain Swing components such as `JTextPane`, `JTextField`, `JTable` etc..

**Do you need a separate model?**

The Swing components have their own models. For example a [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) has a [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) and a [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) will have its own [ComboBoxModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html).

So I would say that having your own models that you synchronize with the UI changes are not the best way to handle things. For example if you have a list of numbers in a `JList`, and the sum in `JTextField` in your `GameView`, having a `GameViewModel` that has `int sum` and `List<Integer> numbers` will duplicate things since the `JList` and `JTextField` already have their own models.

But if you are saving this data to some persistent storage (the database maybe) and fetching the data back to show on the user interface, then having a `GameData` object that has `int sum` and `List<Integer> numbers` will be useful for that purpose. But synchronizing that object with the changes that happen in the UI is still not appropriate. This object should only be filled when the user saves the data(clicks on the save button).

**Do you need a separate controller?**

Swing already has ways to communicate between user interface components and its model via `*Listeners`(`ActionListener`,`ItemListener` etc..). So I don't think that you need a separate class to communicate between the user interface and the UI other than a Listener that comes with Swing.

**Should you put models/views and controllers in different packages?**

No. Why? Classes that communicate with each other should be in the same package. So if you have `GameView`, `GameModel` and `GameController` they should be in the same package. `DiffView`, `DiffModel` and `DiffController` should be in the same package etc.. You shouldn't put `GameView` and `DiffView` in the same package because they are both views and all models in another package etc... If you do that you will have to make most methods public in order for `GameModel` and `GameView` to communicate whereas if you had those in the same package, you could have given them [default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530065/which-is-the-default-access-specifier-in-java) access. Why is this useful? Because the users of your classes(people who will make changes in the future) will know which methods are meant for use outside the package and which methods are not.

Answer (score 1):

1. MathsGame.java = your most bottom layer
2. Views: DiffView.java, GameView.java, EndGameView.java
3. Model: DiffModel.java, GameModel.java, EndGameModel.java
4. Controller: Controller.java (must)
5. MigJPanel.java = layer on top of MathsGame.java
6. ScreenInterface.java = Interface to connect between your MigJPanel.java with your MVC presentation layer.

Please remember to implement Single-Responsibility pattern, in that one class serves only for one purpose only. You cannot mix your main code with controller code. Confusing and not recommended.

Thank you,